Why "dotnet new console" generates a project that cannot be compiled with "dotnet build"? (error CS5001)
First, a little excerpt from Microsoft:

Starting with .NET 6, the project template for new C# console apps generates the following code in the Program.cs file:

// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");


The new output uses recent C# features that simplify the code you need to write for a program.


. . . When you use the newer version, you only need to write the body of the Main method. The compiler generates a Program class with an entry point method and places all your top level statements in that method. The name of the generated method isn't Main, it's an implementation detail that your code can't reference directly. You don't need to include the other program elements, the compiler generates them for you.


Having .NET SDK 8 installed, I opened the command prompt and typed:
dotnet new console --output "D:\User Files\A_L_L\DOWNLOAD_TEMP\test"

It created the project files, one of which is Program.cs. The contents of this file are exactly as described above (in the Microsoft article).
The problem is, I can't build the project. When I type
dotnet build "D:\User Files\A_L_L\DOWNLOAD_TEMP\test\test.csproj" --artifacts-path "D:\User Files\A_L_L\DOWNLOAD_TEMP\test"

the following error is produced:
error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

So... looks like the new program style, generated by the new console, cannot be compiled, because the build command expects the old program style (with Main entry point).
What's going on here? How can I compile the project succesfully?
Thanks

Looks like you've chosen to use a new feature available starting in .NET 8 ( --artifacts-path), did you follow the instructions in Artifacts output layout?

You may consider following the instructions in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78271636/10024425. If you don't want a Main method, then remove --use-program-main from the code in the post

Setting --artifacts-path to a project directory breaks the build for some reason; when used, it's usually meant to be set to a subdirectory of a grandparent, such as D:\User Files\A_L_L\DOWNLOAD_TEMP\artifacts.
However, the bin and obj subdirectories already go into the project directory by default, so you should be able to run
dotnet build "D:\User Files\A_L_L\DOWNLOAD_TEMP\test\test.csproj"

which will build D:\User Files\A_L_L\DOWNLOAD_TEMP\test\bin\Debug\net8.0\test.exe. They won't go into your current working directory or anything.

It is not expecting the old-style Main method entry point. It seems like it simply cannot find any source files to compile. It emits the same error even when I write a proper Main method, or when I make blatant compiler errors like writing Consol instead of Console.
From my experiments, it seems to only behave like this if you use the current directory, or one of its parents as the artifacts path. If you use another directory as the artifacts path, it is able to build the project. e.g.
dotnet build XXX.csproj --artifacts-path SomeSubdirectory

Note that the default artifacts path is already the project directory. If you want to specify it explicitly, using the -p option seems to always work.
dotnet build XXX.csproj -p ArtifactsPath=.

This might be loosely related to this issue.
